# Why is the Prometheus metric 'kube_pod_completion_time' returning empty query results?

Tags: prometheus, grafana, monitoring, dashboard

I'm trying to get terminated pods running time with this query

```
sum by(namespace, pod) (

   (last_over_time(kube_pod_completion_time{pod=~"consumer-deployment.*"}[1d]) 
   - last_over_time(kube_pod_created{pod=~"consumer-deployment.*"}[1d])) 

  or 

time() - min_over_time(kube_pod_created{pod=~"consumer-deployment.*"}[1d])

)
```

but I notice that pod that terminated time pod is not correct it gives me timenow - created time of that pod so if pod created 2 days ago and terminated one day ago it will return 3 days running time (which should be 2 days) so what I did is I removed the "or" part but then I get empty query result

```
sum by(namespace, pod) (

   ((kube_pod_completion_time{}) 
   -(kube_pod_created{})) 
)
```

this metric works

```
kube_pod_created{}
```

so the problem is with

```
kube_pod_completion_time{}
```

here is what i find in kube_state metrics

```
# HELP kube_pod_completion_time [STABLE] Completion time in unix timestamp for a pod.
# TYPE kube_pod_completion_time gauge
```

this last metric when I executed alone it returns
[image]

is there anything I can look into it?