# Prometheus metric return wrong dates and time

Tags: kubernetes, devops, prometheus, grafana

Im using this query to get the runnig time of pods like this

```
sum by(namespace, pod)(
  
  (time() - last_over_time(kube_pod_created{pod=~"consumer-deployment.*"}[1d]))
)
```

the time i get is wrong like 5-6 days and my oldest pod is runnig for 55m
and this query to get creation date of pods also retunr some correct date and some wrong

```
sum by(namespace, pod)(
  
 min_over_time(kube_pod_created{pod=~"consumer-deployment.*"}[1d]))
```

this screenshot shows the pods creation tima asyou can see some or correct (after converting that number) and some are wrong (the ones like 1687511940 are the correct one)

[image]

and I cant get when pod terminated caus this metric doesn't work
[image]

```
kube_pod_competion
```

whats wrong with it ?

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you just use one query ? And as far as i can see you want creation(run) and completion, try this out(you can add the filter as you have consumer-deployment defined):

```
sum by(namespace, pod) (

   (last_over_time(kube_pod_completion_time[1d]) 
   - last_over_time(kube_pod_created[1d])) 

  or 

    (time() - kube_pod_created)

)
```

**UPDATE:**
use process_uptime_seconds, which is exposed by many frameworks such as Prometheus, Grafana

This should return Max uptime seconds durin last 1 day

```
max_over_time(process_uptime_seconds[1d:1h])
```

Comment: 1- kube_pod_completion_time this metric dont work for me it just return an empty result actually I asked question about it  [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76523830/why-is-the-prometheus-metric-kube-pod-completion-time-returning-empty-query-re)
2-even with just 
```kube_pod_created

```
I get wrong creation date like 2076 
3- I need to get only pod that below to my deployment because I need to list them later using spring code

Comment: would you mind to provide a few screenshots or something that helps :)

Comment: Ive added screenshots hope they are usefull,If there is any specific think I have to look into it please tell me and I'll add other pictures

Comment: unfortunatly the query you mentioned in the  updated is not what Im looking for I need to get the creation time and termination time of each pod .

Comment: question because im not sure if you have installed any metrics service such as: kube-state-metrics are you aware of any metrics service installed ?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I didn't install anything. I used Helm for installation, and I found four pods created. They belong to the theme, including the kube_state-metric pod and its corresponding service as well.